# Authentication failure redirect with request params not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to configure my own success and authentication failure handlers.  On authentication failure I want to redirect back to my login page with a request parameter, the presence of this parameter will output the error message on my login page.  However although on error I am getting redirected back to my login page, the request parameter is always `null`.

Code below:

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html").permitAll() 
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")                                               
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .successHandler(successHandler())
            .failureHandler(handleAuthenticationFailure());
}

@Autowired
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //database checks
}
};
}

/**
 * Authentication success handler defines action when successfully authenticated
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler(){
    return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            // custom auth success here
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(savedRequest.getRedirectUrl());
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationFailureHandler handleAuthenticationFailure() {
    return new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
                                            AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {

            // custom failure code here
            setDefaultFailureUrl("/login.html?error=fail");
            super.onAuthenticationFailure(httpRequest, httpResponse, authenticationException);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How do you get the param? Could you please track the network to find whether the url is requested with `error=fail`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // .......

    response.sendRedirect("/login.html?error=fail");    
}
```

**Update:**

It's really important that the "/login.html?error=fail" is added to an authorizeRequests() section otherwise the controller won't pick up the error parameter.

Replace `.antMatchers("/login").permitAll()` with    `.antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()`

Answer (score 3):

Also had problem with params (in my case when login was failed and some request params was added to url it redirected to login page without params).

This solved my problem

```
.antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new in springBoot, if you are using spring boot 2.1.4.RELEASE, try this configuration:

```
http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // URLs matching for access rights
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // form login
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .successHandler(sucessHandler)
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            // logout
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
```

To use the above-defined Spring Security configuration, we need to attach it to the web application. In this case, we don’t need any web.xml:

```
public class SpringApplicationInitializer 


extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] {SecSecurityConfig.class};
}}
```

this means you create the following class which will be instanciated autoatically

SecSecurityConfig.class : is the class where you do all http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()... configurations

source : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

hope it helps :)